# CSS tooltip for simple text

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I would like to use tooltip in a web page with the following constraints:

- Tooltip should work with simple texts, not only with anchors.
- I do not want to use javascript, only css.
- I would like to make it work at least in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

A promising candidate is Eric Meyer's [solution](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/popups/demo.html), but it uses anchors.
Loadaveragezero's [solution](http://loadaveragezero.com/vnav/labs/CSS/tooltips.php) uses span for simple text, but it does not work in Internet Explorer.

I am looking for a working code sample or a link to a solution with the above parameters.

Comment: What's wrong with the title HTML attribute?

Comment: It is not so nice and long comments may be truncated in some browser.
Anyway as a fallback, it is OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, your requirements are unrealistic.  In environments where Javascript may be disabled, I typically will use the `title` attribute to get simple browser tooltips as a fallback, and then enable better looking tooltips via Javascript reading the title attributes (using a framework such as jQuery, or for my personal preference Mootools).

Code sample might be something like (using [Mootools](http://mootools.net/) and the [Tips](http://mootools.net/more) addon):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    // Enable the most basic default tooltips
    var tooltips = new Tips('.tips');
}
</script>

<p>This is some example text in <abbr class="tips" title="Hypertext Markup Language">HTML</abbr> with some <a href="#" class="tips" title="Tooltips are useful tools">tooltips</a> applied to some of it.</p>
```

Answer (score 5):

A solution that meets all your requirements is not possible. IE's respect for `:hover` is limited - Eric Meyer's solution works in IE because it uses anchors. If you want it to work on any element AND work in IE, you have to use JS.

Answer (score 1):

It can't work within your constraints, I'm afraid. Internet Explorer 6 and previous only detects hover over an anchor, so you need to drop a requirement for it to work, either:

- Only has to work in IE7 and newer (in which case Loadaveragezero's solution will work)
- Can use anchors (in which case Eric's solution will work)
- Can use Javascript (in which case there are [many](http://dean.edwards.name/IE7/) [ways](http://jquery.com) to get hovering pre-IE7)